# A problem passing functions from std as a function parameter

Tags: c++, std, std-function

I'm trying to figure out how to pass an `std` function as a parameter. Here is a brief example:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void bar(const double v, std::function<int(int)> foo) {
  std::cout << foo(v) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  bar(-23., std::abs);
}
```

This code fails to compile with a message *no matching function for call to `bar`*, but everything works fine if remove the `std` prefix. What's the deal?

Comment: `std::function` is not the type to be used whenever you want to pass a callable to a function. Anyhow, first step of fixing the error must be reading and understanding the complete compiler error message. You left out the part that is the important one. Please include the complete verbatim error message

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it says there is no overload of `abs` matching `std::function<int(int)>`. But there is an overload for `abs` taking ints. What is the point?

Comment: You cannot take an address of a standard library function (exceot for a few specifically permitted ones). It is undefined behaviour. Further, an overload set cannot convert to `std::function`. Wrapping `std::abs` in a lambda solves both problems.

Comment: Not all `std` functions are *addressable*.  Only the **addressable** functions can be passed by pointer (even if that pointer is just going to be wrapped in a `std::function`); the **non-addressable** functions cannot be passed by pointer.  However, the non-addressable functions can be wrapped in a lambda, and that lambda can be passed by pointer.

Comment: @Eljay never heard of that. Didn't even know non-addressable functions existed. Thanks!

Comment: `std::abs` is overloaded, and this results in a non-deducible context, in the shown code.

Comment: " What is the point?" the point is that there are also other overloads, and there is no way from `bar(-23., std::abs);` to know which one you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::abs()` is not just one function. It's many functions, it's an overload set (see eg here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs). Hence, you cannot take its address like this. And that's the reason you cannot pass it like this to other functions. Even if there was only one overload, most functions in the standard library cannot have their address taken. There are few exceptions only.

Next, `std::function` is not the go-to type to be used always when you need to pass a callable to a function. `std::function` is for when you need a type-erased callable. No problem when you do not understand what it means, you can forget about `std::function` for now. By the time you actually need it, you will know what it's good for.

You can use a lambda expression:

```
template <typename F>
void bar(const double v, F&& foo) {
  std::cout << foo(v) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  bar(-23., [](double a){ return std::abs(a);});
}
```

Note that `[](auto a) { return std::abs(a); }` would work as well. It would result in a class with templated `operator()` that gets instantiated when called. You cannot do the same with a function template, though.

If you want to avoid the template, you can use function pointers:

```
using func_t = double(*)(double);
void bar(const double v, func_t foo) {
  std::cout << foo(v) << std::endl;
}
```

If you remove the `std` prefix, then there is only one overload inherited from C: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs. The others are added by C++. Note that this can have particularly bad consequences when combined with `using namespace std;`.

Comment: I know what type erased means. I would like to avoid using templates as in my real problem this causes some code bloat, so I'd rather stick to passing some callable instead. Besides, all callables I will need to pass will have the same signature.

Comment: @Kaiyakha "I know what type erased means." ok you do not need it here. "I would like to avoid using templates" see edit

Comment: So, as I see, `bar` cannot deduce the type for `std::abs` from `std::function`, right?

Comment: no, the problem starts before. `std::abs` Is a set of overloads. Its nothing which type could be deduced because the overloads have different types

Comment: "Hence, you cannot take its address like this" It isn't clear what is meant by "like this". `int (*pf)(int) = f` works just fine when `f` is an overload and one of the functions in the overload set matches. `std::function<int(int)> pf = f` does not, but it is not intuitively obvious why.